# Update SQL for checked values (Checkbox) in C# webforms

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, webforms

What I want to do is
to update db for checked values. I cant figure out how.
can you guys help me?

[image]

I passed this to view just like this.

```cs
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_Writeday);
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_PriorityGubn);
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_Title);
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_Worker);
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_CloseDate);
oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_WorkStatus);
if (ShowCheckBox == true)
{
    oTR.Cells.Add(oTD_StatusCheck);
}

TmpHTTblWorkList.Rows.Add(oTR);
```

```html
<table class="tbl_list" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" summary="" id="HTTblNoWorkList" runat="server">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" width="105">요청일자</th>
            <th scope="col" width="80">우선순위</th>
            <th scope="col" width="">제목</th>
            <th scope="col" width="80">작성자</th>
            <th scope="col" width="80">작업종료일</th>
            <th scope="col" width="80">상태</th>
            <th scope="col" width="50"><label for="checkNoWorkListAll" class="visuallyhidden"></label><input
                    type="checkbox" id="checkNoWorkListAll" onclick="toggleCheckBox(this);"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context for the question? What is it that you're trying to achieve? What technology you are using to access the database?

Comment: @AndreiIvascu Added an image in the description. What I want to achieve is to get indexes for rows with checkbox Checked, and then update or delete it at once. thank your for your comment.

Comment: could you provide the structure of the table you're editing? What do you use to access the database ADO.NET, Dapper, etc?